# Verilog Logic Parser in Pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to implement a simple logic parser in Python with pyparsing. The parsing is needed later to perform a sanity check. The logic parser is inspired by simpleBool.py and fourFN.py (both by Paul McGuire).

I think I almost solved it, but two of my testcases don't work. I think I probably made a thinking error, but I just cannot find it. So I would be glad, if somebody could check the code for me and help me to understand, why it doesn't work. This is my pyparsing definition:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Keyword, infixNotation, Forward, nestedExpr, srange, opAssoc, nums, Suppress, ZeroOrMore, Group, Optional

TRUE = Keyword("True")
FALSE = Keyword("False")
boolOperand = TRUE | FALSE |  Word(srange("[a-zA-Z0-9_']"))

LPARR,RPARR= map(Suppress, '()')
LPARC,RPARC=map(Suppress,'{}')
LPAR=LPARC | LPARR
RPAR=RPARC | RPARR
expr = Forward()
factor = Group(Optional(LPAR) + expr + Optional(RPAR)) | boolOperand
multibit = Group(Word(nums) + LPARC + factor + RPARC) | factor # should recognize expressions like 2{A & B}
inverted = ZeroOrMore('~') + multibit # should recognize expressions like ~A
leftsideor = ZeroOrMore('|') + inverted # should recognize expressions like |A, but also ~{A & B}
andterm = leftsideor + ZeroOrMore('&' + leftsideor) # should recognize expressions like |A & B
orterm = andterm + ZeroOrMore('|' + andterm)  # should recognize expressions like A | B
expr = Group(Optional(LPAR) + orterm + ZeroOrMore(',' + orterm) + Optional(RPAR)) | orterm # {A,B,C&D}, (A,B,C&D)
```

And below are the testcases.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = True
    q = False
    r = True
    tests = ["p",
             "q",
             "p & q",
             "p & ~q",
             "(p & ~q)",
             "{p & ~q}",
             "~~p",
             "q | ~p & r",
             "q | ~p | ~r",
             "q | ~(p & r)",
             "p | q | r",
             "p | q | r & False",
             "(p | q | r) & False",
             "|p",
             "{p,q,d&c,r}",
             "{2{p&q}}",
             "{p,q,d&c,3'd4}",
             "{2{p_1_&q}}",
             "{2{p23padsf_1_&q_2_3}}",
             "{~ITHERMSEL, ~IUNITSEL, ~IAVGSEL1} & {{2{EQEN}} , EQ3D }",
             "{{~ITHERMSEL, ~IUNITSEL, ~IAVGSEL1} & {{2{EQEN}} , EQ3D }}",
             "~(p & q)"
            ]


    print()
    for t in tests:
        print t
        res = expr.parseString(t)[0]
        print res

        print
```

The following test cases have an issue:

```
{2{p&q}}
```

This is parsed just as 2. I think here the issue is that 2 could be a boolOperand, but how can I make the booloperand to exclude numbers (e.g. A2 is ok, only 2 not)

```
{{~ITHERMSEL, ~IUNITSEL, ~IAVGSEL1} & {{2{EQEN}} , EQ3D }}
```

Without the outmost curly brackets, it works. With the additional brackets, there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpleVerilogLogic.py", line 104, in <module>
    res = expr.parseString(t)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.3-py2.6.egg/pyparsing.py", line 1125, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException:  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
```

But I don't understand where the issue is. The same issue also occurs with

```
~(p & q)
```

I think I have somehow a fundamental misunderstanding. I checked different examples, but I couldn't figure out the solution. I would really appreciate, if someone could give me an advice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Since `expr` is a Forward, your assignment `expr = Group(Optional(LPAR) + orterm...` is incorrect, should be `expr <<= Group(Optional(LPAR) + orterm...`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Thank you very much for your answer. This was a stupid error. However, if I do 'expr  << =', then I receive the error message 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp'. I looked at fourFN.py, and there expr is defined as Forward, then used in atom and then injected at the end. BTW: I bought your book.

Comment: I solved this error: The problem was the Optional statement in `factor = Group(Optional(LPAR) + expr + Optional(RPAR)) | boolOperand`